# Rest API to v-data-table using v-select but v-data-table can't show so I use v-for to

Tags: vue.js, axios, v-for, v-select, v-data-table

**Purpose:**

- 1.Rest API >>> by axios
- 2.Select category >>> by v-select
- *3.Show table >>> by v-data-table* but i can't show table so I use v-for to show but I got this

[here what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgMea.png)
it show many table (according to the number of data sets)

Here is my code
HTML Part

```
  <template>
  <v-container>
    <h1>JSON Data</h1>
    <span>Data Test Table For Current Sensor Table</span>
    <!-- Choose -->
    <div id="top">
      <!-- left-right -->
      <v-row align-center>
        <!-- title -->
        <v-col cols="5">
          <v-subheader>Choose Generation: {{ selected }}</v-subheader>
        </v-col>
        <!-- dropdown -->
        <v-col cols="7">
          <v-select :items="items" v-model="selected" dense></v-select>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </div>
    <!-- Button -->
    <v-btn block v-on:click="getData()">Load Data</v-btn>
    <div v-for="(item, i) in data" :key="i" >
    <v-data-table :items="data" :headers="headers" :items-per-page="5">
      <template slot="data" slot-scope="props">
        <td>{{ props.data.userId }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.data.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.data.title }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
    </div>

    <!-- Test -->
    <span class="data_id">***{{ data }} </span><br />
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Script Part

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "Current",
  data: () => ({
    items: ["albums", "todos", "posts"],
    selected: "",

    headers: [
      { text: "USER_ID", align: "start", sortable: false, value: "userId" },
      { text: "ID", value: "id" },
      { text: "TITLE", value: "title" },
    ],
    data: [],
  }),

  methods: {
    getData() {
      axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/" + this.selected)
        .then((response) => {
          this.data = response.data;
        })
        .catch((err) => alert(err));
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getData();
  },
};
</script>
```

**Vue&Vuetify is new to me. If you have any suggestions, please tell me.**

I try to remove div  `<div v-for="(item, i) in data" :key="i" ></div>` but when I refresh this page it gone and show only empty table
[show only empty table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3y8v.png)

Comment: Do you want to show just one table? remove the div ` <div v-for="(item, i) in data" :key="i" ></div>`

Comment: I already remove div ` <div v-for="(item, i) in data" :key="i" ></div>`
but when I refresh this page it gone and show only empty table.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove v-for.
Because v-data-table displays table for data you passed, it will display same table as much as count of items in the data.

https://prnt.sc/1nsxc7w